# Get the number I am calling in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, phone-number, telephonymanager

I need to get the number that I am calling from my Android device programmatically. What I'm doing now is the following:

I listen for `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` being broadcasted which means that either I am being called or am calling (or receiving an SMS etc).

In a `BroadcastReceiver` I retrieve the extra `incoming_number` from the intent. Sadly I cannot get the number which is being called if *I* initiate the call though. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Intent `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` in this intent you can get the extra `Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER` which contains the outgoing number.

The intent is issued if a new outgoing call is intanciated.

You will need the Permission `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` for this.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    Log.d("OutgoingCallReceiver",phonenumber);
    Log.d("OutgoingCallReceiver",intent.getExtras().toString());
}
```