# How can I get number to call to my app

Tags: android, call, broadcast

When user text number and press call button, there is two option now, default call and my app icon. That's ok. Then If user click my app icon, My app start to running and in my app,I want to get number to call. No previous number.

[image]

When user press green call button, and choose my app icon, then I want to get red circle number to my activity as a string. Is it possible ?

In my main activity I have static string tel.
My activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    call cc=new call();
    tv.setText(tel);
```

My broadcast class:

```
public class call extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    MainActivity.tel=phonenumber;
}
}
```

I cant get number to textview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get number i am calling in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337054/get-number-i-am-calling-in-android)

Comment: @NadeemIqbal I just add my code. Can you look now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get **Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER** string in intent **android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL**... see [Intent.Extra_phone_number](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER) and [NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) here.

Thanks to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337401/3884250)

Comment: ok but what am I going to add my activity ? I mean I created a class it extends BroadcastReceiver. and it still not working